# Where can I go to see all the associated domains that are linked to one domain on a specific server?

Tags: domains

What site can show me all of the related sites on a specific server when I enter in one domain name? I just want to know how many other sites are hosted on the same server as the domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a reverse IP lookup. I always use the one from [YouGetSignal](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/). This will take a short time and then it will show all the domain names found on the same IP the domain name you entered is hosted on.